# how to find the name attribute is present or not in below html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML Details:

```
<iframe width="465" height="285" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7KS8KGGTpkI?wmode=transparent&amp;vq=hd720"></iframe> 
<p>aksfasjfksalfsfsjkf</p>
<h3>asfasdfasdfasfas</h3>
<iframe width="465" height="285" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7KS8KGGTpkI?wmode=transparent&amp;vq=hd720" name="test1"></iframe>
```

I need to find the name attribute in iframe. I have to group iframe tag based on whether the name attribute is present in tag or not.

HI friends Above html, i want to add the name attribute in iframe tag.when iframe tag isn't containing the name attribute.

Comment: What kind of *detail* `aksfasjfksalfsfsjkf` is?

Comment: @HashemQolami see incoming edit

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: guys understand it now?

Comment: var t = "<iframe width='465' height='285' frameborder='0' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/7KS8KGGTpkI?wmode=transparent&vq=hd720' allowfullscreen='true'></iframe><p test='new'>test</p><iframe width='465' height='285' frameborder='0' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/7KS8KGGTpkI?wmode=transparent&vq=hd720' name='this' allowfullscreen='true'></iframe>";
            alert($(t).find('iframe:first').attr('name'));
            alert($(t).find('iframe[name]').val());

Answer (score 0):

```
  var t =  $( "iframe[name='test1']" ); // is this what you wanted?
```

Comment: thanks,but how to find the iframe name attribute there or not. how do i print in alert message

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery it becomes easier using the dial next to the name attribute you find which has the attribute.

```
var iframeWithNameAttr = $("iframe[name]") ;// to search all iframe with name attribute
var iframeWithoutNameAttr = $("iframe").not("[name]") ;// to search all iframe without name attribute
var iframeWithFooNameAttr = $("iframe[name=foo]") ;// to seach all iframe with name equals to foo
```

to more information about jQuery attribute selectors... http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Edited:

if you want to add the tag name in the iframe without the tag, you can use the form below:

```
var iframesWithoutName = $("iframe",t).not("[name]");
$(iframesWithoutName).attr("name", "insert the name here!");
```

Below the jsFiddle with you example working...

http://jsfiddle.net/Castrolol/FNfB8/

Comment: thanks, but i used this it return null. var iframeWithoutNameAttr = $(t).find("iframe").not("[name]");

Comment: HI friends Above html, i want to add the name attribute in iframe tag.when iframe tag isn't containing the name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var t =  $("iframe[name]").attr("name");
```

It returns "name" attribute of that iframe that has: http://jsfiddle.net/rb8vE/